# Kivy - Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, kivy

I'm experimenting with kivy, I keep getting segmentation fault from following code and can't figure it out. I suspect there is something wrong with my understanding of classes in python.

By trial and error found commenting

> #p.open()

Stops the problem, yet I cannot solve nor understand the error. 
Thanks

Error:

> Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Python code

```
class popper(Popup):
    yazi= StringProperty("notsetyet")

    def __init__(self, texty):
       self.yazi = text
       print texty


class boxxy(BoxLayout):
   ...
   def on_press(self):
      p = popper("test_value")
      p.open()       
   ...
```

.kv file

```
<popper>

    title: "Warn"
    size_hint: 0.5 , 0.5
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text:     root.yazi
        Button:
            text: "close"
            on_press: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what's causing your problem, but there are multiple bugs in your code. Also, it's best if you can provide a full working minimal example, that makes it a lot easier to debug.

The main bug (that may well cause this) is that you don't call `super(Popper, self).__init__(**kwargs)` in your `__init__` definition (which probably also needs to be defined with `def __init__(texty, **kwargs)` to catch extra arguments). This is vital because the normal `__init__` sets up all the normal widget and popup behaviour.

You also have `self.yazi = text` when you mean `self.yazi = texty`.

Finally, it is a normal Python convention to have class names start with a capital letter. Although this is normally just a stylistic guide and not a requirement, I think kv language depends on it sometimes, so you may get crashes or strange behaviour if you don't do so.